# "closure preserves homeomorphism"

Tags: general-topology

Let me explain the title of the problem and the problem very clearly :

If $X$ and $Y$ are subsets of a topological spaces $A$ and $B$ respectively, which are homeomorphic in the respective subspace topology, does it imply that their closure $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$ are homeomorphic ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint**. Consider $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0, 1)$.

Comment: Not really a *hint*, per se....

Answer (score 1):

To the edited question, the answer is no. Consider $Y=X=A=(0,1)$, $B=[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

For another mode of failure....

Let $A$ and $B$ the the Euclidean plane. Let $X$ be the unit interval $(0,1)$ on the $x$-axis. Let $Y$ be the unit circle minus the point $(-1,0)$.